# An open set that has no volume

Tags: measure-theory, volume

> Let $\mathbf Q\cap[0,1]=\{q_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(q_n-\frac1{2^{n+2}},q_n+\frac1{2^{n+2}})$. Show that $A$ has no volume.

Here "volume of a set $B$" means the Riemann-integral of the characteristic function of $B$, 
$$v(B):=\int_R \chi_B,$$
where $R$ is a rectangle that contains $B$.

I know (by Lebesgue Theorem) that a (bounded) set has volume iff its boundary has measure zero. However, I'm not sure how to show that $\partial A$ has measure zero.
Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by volume?  Any nonempty open set has positive Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @littleO I mean "Jordan measure" (in the context of the Riemann integral).

Comment: @MaikPickl Yes, I want to show that $\partial A$ has non-zero measure. Maybe I didn't explain myself properly. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated in the comments, a bounded set $A$ is Jordan measurable iff its boundary has Lebesgue measure zero. Let's calculate the Lebesgue measure of the boundary.

Observe that the Lebesgue measure of $A$ fullfills the following inequality (use the sub-additivity of the measure):

\begin{eqnarray}
\mu(A)&\leq& \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu\left(\left(q_n-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}},q_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\right)\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\cdot \dfrac{1}{2^{n+2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \dfrac{1}{2^{n+1}}\\
&=&\dfrac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}

But now observe that $[0,1]\subset cl(A)$ since $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]\subset A$ and $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Therefore $\mu(cl(A))\geq 1 >1/2 $ and it follows that the boundary has non-zero Lebesgue measure.